# Real eigenvalues, similar symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

I know that symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues, and that non-symmetric matrices that are similar to symmetric matrices must also have real eigenvalues, but is the converse true?

That is, if a matrix has real eigenvalues, must there exist a similar matrix that is symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Counterexample:
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
is not similar to any symmetric matrix.

On the other hand, every *diagonalizable* matrix with real eigenvalues is similar to a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example. Indeed, I am indeed looking at diagonalizable matrices.  Can you explain in more detail or sketch out a proof if it is short, or point me to a text that shows this?

Comment: @science404 If a matrix is diagonalizable, it is similar to a diagonal matrix, which is symmetric

Comment: Of course, thanks!